# Cant seem to properly scrape the US army website for data

Tags: php, xpath, html-parsing

I was trying to scrape a page of MOS' for the ARMY but it seem that i am doing it wrong.

```
<?php
    $army = "http://www.goarmy.com/careers-and-jobs/browse-career-and-job-categories/administrative-support.AR-both.html";
$fp = file_get_contents($army);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($fp);
$classes = $dom->getElementsByTagName("div");
foreach($classes as $class){        
    if($class->getAttribute("class") == "job-desc")continue;

    foreach($class->getElementsByTagName("a") as $c){
        echo $c;
    }
    break;
}
?>
```

is what i was trying, but i cant seem to get it right.   I was hoping there was a jQuery like selector tool, or XPATH sort of way to handle what i was looking for.

im trying to find:

```
$("div.job-desc > h4 > a").text();
$("div.job-desc > ul > li").text();
```

I am working on an National MOS dictionary for every branch, and then expanding to other countries in the near future.

I was thinking that i could modify the jquery-like selector to xpath, but it seems that XPath might be something just for XML, and not nessicarily an HTML Document.

Comment: In my experience XPath works pretty well with HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use this:

http://davidwalsh.name/php-notifications

and do stuff like:

download and include:simple_html_dom.php
do:

```
$html = file_get_html($army);
foreach($html->find('div.job-desc > h4 > a') as $row){
   echo $row->innertext."\n";
}
```

it will do what you wnat.

to prettfy, it puts each on a new line...  If needed, parse the *$row->innertext* as needed.